# How can i store the user inputs from repeating the same enter the information and then print all of them after typing "no"

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, input, store

I was doing a student info listing which was input by a user.But i can't seem to breakthrough the problem  of adding another list of info after typing "yes" which indicates the code to add another student to be put on the list.

I tried doing the switch cases within switch cases incase the user wants multiple student info to be listed.But i ran out of ideas.I expect it to repeat the whole enter the information and store it from  the line (Do you want to add more? YES OR NO),but it just repeats and i cant store it once i type "no".

Here is my code doing it:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test3d {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String[][] students = new String[50][50]; 

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    final String toUpperCase;
    String decision ="";
    boolean yn = true;
    
    //loop to request to fill array   
    while(yn){
            System.out.println("Enter Student ID Number: ");
            while(in.hasNext()){
            int row = 0;
            students[row][0] = in.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter Student Fullname: ");
            students[row][1] = in.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter Student College: ");
            students[row][2] = in.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter Student Program: ");
            students[row][3] = in.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Record Successfully Saved");
            System.out.print("Do you want to add more? YES/NO ");
            decision=in.nextLine();
            
            switch(decision) 
            {
            case "yes":
                yn=true;
                System.out.println("Enter Student ID Number: ");
                while(in.hasNext()) {
                students[row][0] = in.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Enter Student Fullname: ");
                students[row][1] = in.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Enter Student College: ");
                students[row][2] = in.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Enter Student Program: ");
                students[row][3] = in.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Do you want to add more? YES/NO ");
                }
                
            case "no":
                yn=false;
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("ID NUMBER     STUDENT NAME      COLLEGE      PROGRAM ");
                System.out.println(students[row][0]+"       "+students[row][1].toUpperCase()+"       "+students[row][2].toUpperCase()+"          "+students[row][3].toUpperCase());
                break;
                                    
            }
            }           
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using your IDE's debugging features, single-step through your program and watch your variables, especially `row`. When going to the second student's data entry, does it have the value that you expect? Besides coding, the ability to debug a program is very important. If your course doesn't cover it, learn it on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

I would strongly advise to follow @Ralf Kleberhoff suggestion in the comment. Debugging is a strong skill and tool and you must control it.

---

It seems you are not incrementing `row` after adding an additional student.

```
System.out.print("Do you want to add more? YES/NO ");
decision=in.nextLine();
            
switch(decision) 
{
  case "yes":
  yn=true;
  **row++**
  System.out.println("Enter Student ID Number: ");
  while(in.hasNext()) {
  students[row][0] = in.nextLine();
```

After you receive a `no` as an input - you should iterate and print all of the students the user had added -

```
for(int i = 0; i <= row; i++){
  var output = String.format("Id: %s, fullname: %s, collage: %s, program: %s", students[row][0], students[row][1], students[row][2], students[row][3]);
  System.out.println(output);
}
```

In addition, inside the `switch` in the `yes` case, in case I add an additional student and then select `no`, the loop is not broken and another student will be asked to be added, and in case `yes` is selected - row is being initialized again to 0. I would suggest to initialize `row` outside of the `while` loop.